# Facebook: Like Button v/s Wall Post Like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I just went through this nice [Like button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

As per my understanding the Like button is used on a website and when the user clicks the Like button on website, a story appears in the user's friends' News Feed with a link back to your website.

So is this Like button same as the Like button that is present to very Wall posting. What i mean is whenever an activity is posted to Users wall it has the default Like button and comment button too. Are these two likes same?

Also if i want my application to find out which user clicked the like on the wall posting, can it be done? Please Correct me if the question is inappropriate or incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"? Same in what way?

Comment: Same in the sense when a user clicks a Like button on your page, a connection is made between your page and the user. Does clicking on Wall post like connects your app and the Wall post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user clicks 'Like' then an edge is created between him and the liked object on the fb graph, regardless of where the action was made.

The app has nothing to do with this process, the user liked a post on a wall, why would it "connect the app and the wall post"?

Check out the [Like fql table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) which can be used to return `the IDs of users who like a given object (video, note, link, photo, or album)`

Comment: So this means if my app posts something on the users Wall then using the post ID of it i can query using Like fql doc as you suggested and get the user ids who liked the Post. This way my application can find out which user clicked the like on the wall posting,

Comment: Post iD is generated by Facebook if i am not wrong. Is there a way to get a particular Post ID?

Comment: Who made the post? Your app, or did the user do it using the normal facebook interface ?

Comment: My application it may be a facebook application or my web application posting on users behalf

Comment: Well then, when you make a post facebook returns the id of it, just use that.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the FAQ'S in the facebook documentation for the like button, to know which 
user has clicked the 'like' button.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

> What analytics are available about the Like button?

If you visit facebook.com/insights and register your domain, you can see the number
of likes on your domain each day and the demographics of who is clicking the Like 
button.

Comment: Ya this makes sense but what about the demographics of who is clicking the Like on the User Wall Post?